# Config file for SFTP Server

Tags: php

I'm trying to hide my log in information for my sftp server. I've tried to use a config.php file but it does not work.

My config file:

```
 <?php

  define('serveradress','server');
  define('12345','serverPort');
  define('testcustomer','serverUser');
  define('testpasswort,'srvpswrd');

  ?>
```

My code:

```
include 'config.php';
$server = 'server';
$serverPort = 'serverPort';
$serverUser = 'serverUser';
$srvpswrd = 'srvpswrd';
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, $serverPort);
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, $serverUser, $srvpswrd)){
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Hide it from who?

Comment: for security reasons

Comment: Ok, it's your opinion. http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php - here is documentation how to use define in php.

Comment: You're not using any of your `define`s in your code, you're using strings

Comment: okay, i need to remove ' ' 
but still does'nt work.

Comment: How does moving the credentials to another file hide them? Anyway, your question has nothing to do with SFTP, so I'm removing that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the parameters in the wrong order.

```
define('12345','serverPort');
```

Here's how it's supposed to go:

```
bool define ( string $name , mixed $value )
```

Also, the constant should be all caps. It's [best practices](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) but, also, in PHP 7.3, case insensitivity for constants is going away:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/case_insensitive_constant_deprecation

At that point what you'd do is this:

```
$server = SERVER;
$serverPort = SERVER_PORT;
$serverUser = SERVER_USER;
$srvpswrd = SERVER_PSWRD;
```

Although if you're doing that you might as well do this:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect(SERVER, SERVER_PORT);
```